# Access Static Resource Zip to then Deploy into Salesforce

Tags: deployment, static-resources, zip

I have a zipped folder containing Reports and their xmls, along with a "package.xml" uploaded into my Salesforce's Static Resources.`

I'm trying to retrieve this Zip using `StaticResource staticResource = [SELECT Body FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'ZippedReports' WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];`

Then I attempt to deploy the Reports with this code:

```
 public static void deployReportsFromZip() {
        String zipFileContent = readZipFileFromStaticResource('ZippedReports');
        System.debug(zipFileContent);

        MetadataService.MetadataPort metadataPort = MetadataUtility.createService();
        
        MetadataService.DeployOptions deployOptions = new MetadataService.DeployOptions();
        deployOptions.performRetrieve = false;
        deployOptions.rollbackOnError = true;

        MetadataService.AsyncResult asyncResult = new MetadataService.AsyncResult();
            asyncResult = metadataPort.deploy(zipFileContent, deployOptions);
            System.debug('This is the asyncResult: ' + asyncResult);
            while (!asyncResult.done || asyncResult.done == null) {
                System.debug('Waiting for deployment');
            }
            MetadataService.DeployResult deployResult = metadataPort.checkDeployStatus(asyncResult.id, true);
            System.debug('This is the deployResult: ' + deployResult);
        
    }
```

I hover then receive this error: `Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: '' is not valid for type xsd:boolean, should be '0', '1', 'true' or 'false' faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=`
in my Dev Console's debug Execution Log when the code runs. I can't seem to find any idea why this is happening and would appreciate some direction!

This is the content of my package.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>56.0</version>
</Package>
```